# Maftir Yonah riches?

Tags: minhag, synagogue, yom-kippur, segulah, yonah-jonah-book-of

It is common tradition that the one who purchases the rights to Maftir Yonah will be blessed with much wealth the following year. Are there any sources for this?

Comment: It's a siman, not a sibah. People who can drop 10K (50K?) on Maftir Yonah tend to be people who have a nice amount of available wealth. People with available wealth can invest it. People who invest get even richer.

Answer (score 4):

The minhag definitely seems to have some roots in the Lubavitcher chassidus.

HoRav Gavriel Zinner shlita in his Nitei Gavriel on [Yom Kippur 62:16](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=402&hilite=) writes as follows:

> העולה לתורה שלישי מפטיר בספר יונה להורות כוח התשובה והעולם מהדרין ביותר לקנות ההפטרה זו לעלות לעשירות וכל מילי דמיטב
>
> The one is called up to the Torah for "shlishi" (the third portion) receives the Maftir of Yonah to (lit. teach) instill the power of teshuva, and the world makes (the honour) it more mehadrin (lit. beautiful) by buying this haftarah which is a segulah for wealth and all good things.

The footnote there reads as follows:

> כ"כ בספר המלך במסיבו ח"א עמוד ע"ג שכ"ק אדמו"ר מהריי"ץ אמר שמפטיר יונה מעניק כוח לתשובה והוא גם סגולה לעשירות. וכ"כ עוד עמוד רמ"ח שהרה"ג מהרש"ג ז"ל שאל את גיסו כ"ק אדמו"ר מליובאוויטש זצ"ל למה רבים משתדלים להפטיר מפטיר יונה, והשיב שיש בכך הרבה סגולות
>
> So it is written in the [sefer Melech Bimsibo vol. 1 p.73](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=28803&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=65) that the Admor MaHaRayitz said that the Maftir Yonah gives power to teshuva and is also a segulah for wealth. Similarly, it writes further on p.248 that the MaHarshag z"l asked his brother-in-law the Admor of Lubavitch zt"l why many people endeavour to receive the maftir Yonah and he answered that there is there in it many segulos.

And if your Yiddish is any good, this point can also be found in the [Rebbe Rayatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Yitzchak_Schneersohn)'s [Sefer HaMaamarim 5711 p.91](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31666&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=) (starting on the final paragraph and continuing over the page).

Comment: Ooh Yiddish fun

Comment: Not sure the Sefer HaMaamarim is relevant, except for the phrase מצד כמה ענינים װאָס זײנען תלוים בזה.

Comment: @magicker72 - did you read over the page??

Comment: @Dov Yes, to the end of אות ד. What part mentions segulos?

Comment: No my point was there too it mentions the concept of buying the honour of maftir yonah. From what I understand he does mention the relative merits of buying it